# What is the cleanest way to evaluate both fields on query builder

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, model, laravel-query-builder

There are `first_name`, `mid_name` and `last_name` fields in my model. And I am receiving 2 fields (`name`, `last_name`) with POST request. I am sure `last_name` will be there for sure, but I want to be able to compare `first_name` or `mid_name` with name.

The issue here is, I don't want to repeat myself but I couldn't figure out a cleaner way.

```
$query = User::where('last_name', $request->last_name);

if ($request->name) {
    $query = $query->where('first_name', $request->name);
}

$result = $query->get();
```

If I chain, `->orWhere('mid_name', $request->name)` inside the if statement, I will end up repeating myself for rechecking for last_name.

I tried dividing this line:

```
$query = User::where('last_name', $request->last_name);
```

to this but it doesn't find even the last_name (probably because I am accessing the class?):

```
$query = User::class;
$lastnameQuery = $query->where('last_name', $request->last_name);
```

How would you approach a scenario like this to achieve it in a clean way?

Comment: What's wrong with `orWhere`, it's the simpler way of doing the simple thing.

Comment: `$query->where('first_name', $request->name)->orWhere('last_name', $request->last_name)->where('mid_name', $request->mid_name);` - I'd like this if I could separate them if I could separate them just like my last chunk of code. (Nothing wrong though, just questioning if there is a cleaner way to write it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a `orWhere` it could be done easily, for example:

```php
$query = User::where('last_name', $request->last_name);

if ($request->name) {
    $query = $query->where(function($query) use ($request) {
        $query->where('first_name', $request->name)
              ->orWhere('mid_name', $request->name);
    });
}

$result = $query->get();
```

The `closure` is required here to separately apply the `orWhere` only on the `first_name` and `mid_name`, so the pseudo query would be something like this:

```
WHERE last_name = 'doe' AND (first_name = 'john' OR mid_name = 'john')
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was looking for. Very interesting approach!

Comment: The `closure`  is required to separate the  `where` clause.

Comment: There was a typo `;`, fixed it.